# Throwing IllegalArgumentException in Parameterized Constructor Java

Tags: java, class, constructor

Here is my code:

```
public StyleRay(Point endpoint, int direction, String style)
{
    if(endpoint == null || style == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("A point or string cannot be null");
    else if(direction < 0 || direction > 359)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The direction needs to be between 0 and 360");
    else if(style != "dotted" || style != "dashed" || style != "double")
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The style needs to be double, dashed, or dotted");
    else
    {
        this.endpoint = new Point(endpoint);
        this.direction = direction;
        this.style = new String(style);
    }
}
```

Here are the requirements for my assignment:

> A parameterized constructor that will receive the endpoint (as a Point) and the direction (as an int)
>   and the style (as a String). If the Point that is received or the String that is received are null, then
>   throw new IllegalArgumentException(<”your descriptive String here”>);
>   If the direction is not between 0 and 359 (inclusive), then
>   throw new IllegalArgumentException(<”your descriptive String here”>);
>   Also, if the style that is received is not equal to “double” or “dashed” or “dotted” then
>   throw new IllegalArgumentException(<”your descriptive String here”>);
>   If the direction and style are OK, then initialize the data to the Point, int, and String that are
>   received. Be sure deep copies are used in this case.

I know that something is wrong with the part where I check if the style is dotted, dashed, or double because when I comment it out everything works except for that part. With how it is now it just throws IllegalArgumentExceptions at everything.

I have a feeling that this is a pretty simple fix and I'm just not doing something right but I am a beginner at this and not sure what I should try next.

I originally tried it as,

```
else if(style.equals("dotted") == false) || etc, etc, etc)
```

but that didn't work either.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (!style.equals("dotted") && !style.equals("dashed") && !style.equals("double"))        
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The style needs to be double, dashed, or dotted");
```

Comment: That worked thank you. So the "!" in the front is telling it to check if it doesn't equal I'm assuming?

Comment: Great! Yes, it is.